# regex capturing only page number

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I would like to write the following regex to capture only page number instead of "/p2". 
Also I need to capture the first group if pages are not set.

Can anyone lead me to correct results. Thanks

```
~(.*)/c(?:(/p[0-9]+))~is

Match 1
Full match  0-34    `http://localhost:8080/clothes/c/p2`
Group 1.    0-29    `http://localhost:8080/clothes`
Group 2.    31-34   `/p2`
```

https://regex101.com/r/prgF1H/2

Comment: Use `(.*)/c(?:/p([0-9]+))`

Comment: What do you mean by "if pages are not set"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(.*)/c(?:/(p[0-9]+))?
```

Moved the forward slash out of the capture group, and made the page number optional (therefore matching the entire string)

See it [here](https://regex101.com/r/prgF1H/3)

**Edit**

If you mean the "only the page number" bit to mean instead of "/p2" you get "2":

```
(.*)/c(?:/p([0-9]+))?
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. it's just perfect. would you mind to look after this regex? what's wrong https://regex101.com/r/prgF1H/4

Comment: @Kovi, if you want it to just match lines with a page number: [Try this](https://regex101.com/r/9F8m0Q/1), if not, then you'll have to explain your problem to me just a little more

Comment: ok, let me to explain to you. I have 3 groups that I want to capture if they are sets. Basically first group is category, second are filters and the last one is page. If there are no filters and page set I want to capture only the first group "clothes". If category and page is set I want to capture the category and the page. If both are sets I want to capture all grouos. See here https://regex101.com/r/9F8m0Q/2

Comment: @Kovi so maybe more [like this](https://regex101.com/r/prgF1H/7) `^(.*)/c(?:/(?:(.*?))?/?(p[0-9]+)?)?$`

Comment: yes. this is what i want. thank you a lot! i'll try to figure what u did there :D thanks!